# ¿Cómo introducir un componente dentro de otro?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, component

Tengo un componente del tipo selec que muestra las encuestas creadas en la base de datos. El componente select se tiene que mostrar dentro del componente de preview, y tiene que mostrar los nombres de las encuestas y permitir elegir una para ser renderizada en el componente preview. Logre armar y que funcionen los componentes pero no se como lograr lo mencionado.

¿Me podrian orientar como hacerlo?. Aún sigo aprendiendo. Gracias!

Comment: podríamos reducir la pregunta a, introducir un componente, dentro de otro?

Comment: A esta pregunta no le veo ninguna relación con `nodejs`

Comment: Corregi lo que comentan, soy nuevo aquí muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizaré un ejemplo genérico para ayudarte.

Suponiendo que tengo el siguiente componente:

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is header component.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

y suponiendo que esta es el componente en el que necesito implementar el componente base:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

agregando la importación del componente `Header`en el componente `App`, puedo utilizarlo como si fuera una etiqueta HTML, de la siguiente manera:

```
import Header from './components/Header'; //traemos el componente a insertar
 
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header /> //insertamos donde haga falta.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```